# sheets add-on giving 1-hr trigger error, even when there are no triggers installed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote my first google app script with simple menu & sidebar; it works fine from script-editor but when I publish it as a 'sheets add-on' then 
1. one of the textbox's in sidebar is missing
2. sidebar's submit/cancel buttons are not working

Further more, on executing other menu items ... I keep on getting "the recurrence interval for an add-on trigger must be at least one hour".  Yes, I had installed 10 mins triggers before, but now I have removed them all ... just to make the 'add-on'  work cleanly. I also renamed onOpen(), but no respite.

I am stuck, dont know what to try next ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After making changes to add-on you need to republish new version, then old error will dissapear